# Msys2 cannot resolve dependencies with python + qt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-2.x, msys2

I mean to upgrade `python-pyqt5` (which corresponde to python3), but there are issues with `python2`+`qt5`:

```
$ pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5 and mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common are in conflict. Remove mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common? [Y/n]
:: mingw-w64-x86_64-python and mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 are in conflict. Remove mingw-w64-x86_64-python3? [Y/n]
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common' required by mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pyqt5
```

**How can I deal with this?**
I do not know if there is any suitable replacement for `mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pyqt5`.

Comment: Did you do a system upgrade before? `pacman -Suy`. If that doesn't help try uninstalling the "python2-" packages, as Python 2 support was dropped in MSYS2 starting this year and all packages got removed. For example `pacman -R mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pyqt5`

Comment: @lazka - This is a significant change. Do you mean that all packages depending on python2 (including python2 itself) will be/were removed from msys2 repos?
In that case, one should upgrade all other scripts/packages that use features from python2 not compatible with python3...
PS: Yes I did a system upgrade, and it didn't help. So far, I don't dare removing all python2 from my system, but I guess I will have no choice as a progression.

Comment: @sancho-s-reinstate-monica yes, most have been removed, the only thing that we plan to keep for a bit longer is Python 2 itself and pip/setuptools so you can install packages from pypi. `pacman -Qm` should show you a list of packages which you have installed but are no longer in the pacman repo.